# Deleting observations in group categories in R using condition

Tags: r

As I study R, I had the new question. Can you tell me, i have the goods categories. The goods of each categories have the price.Is it possible to write string in R so that, if value of observation exceeds the average of group by more than 500 000 in this commodity category, then this obs. would removed from the analysis. I.E, I need from all commodity categories (grouping variable) to remove the observations, values of which more the 500 000 of the average for the group.

```
data = read.table(textConnection("
cat price
1   100000
1   200000
1   300000
1   400000
1   1000000
2   100000
2   200000
2   50000
2   100000
2   1000000
2   2000000
"),head=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

With `base`:

```
subset(data,!data$price>(ave(mydata$price,mydata$cat)+500000))
```

Result:

```
cat   price 
1    1  100000        
2    1  200000        
3    1  300000        
4    1  400000        
6    2  100000        
7    2  200000        
8    2   50000        
9    2  100000        
10   2 1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  filter(price - mean(price) <= 500000)
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
Groups: cat [2]

    cat   price
  <int>   <int>
1     1  100000
2     1  200000
3     1  300000
4     1  400000
5     2  100000
6     2  200000
7     2   50000
8     2  100000
9     2 1000000
```

Comment: I try win one problem. 'df %>%
+   group_by(mydata$ca) %>%
+   filter(price - mean(mydata$price) <= 500000)
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"'  .What's wrong. I thought i can self decide, but i can't

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using standard evaluation and list subsetting in piped code where `dplyr` expects non-standard evaluation. (It didn't help that I named your data frame `df` instead of `data`.) So maybe try again, just substituting `data` for `df` at the start of that block of piped code. DO NOT add back `mydata$`.

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'cat', we subset the rows of Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) using the logical condition

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,  .SD[(price - mean(price)) <= 500000], cat]
```

Or we can use the row index (`.I`)

```
setDT(data)[data[,  .I[(price - mean(price)) <= 500000], cat]$V1]
#    cat   price
#1:   1  100000
#2:   1  200000
#3:   1  300000
#4:   1  400000
#5:   2  100000
#6:   2  200000
#7:   2   50000
#8:   2  100000
#9:   2 1000000
```